# Error gathering and reporting for ASP.NET MVC

Tags: elmah, error-reporting

Is there any tool like ELMAH for error gathering of an ASP.NET MVC that, unlike ELMAH, can work indistinctly on x86 and x64. Currently one single ELMAH cannot do that because of its dependency on SQLite which has native code (for one or the other platform and not both).

Even though my setup is fully x64, Casini, the web server used by Visual Studio for coding is, like Visual Studio, x86. So, I'm looking for an alternative to ELMAH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAC both versions of SQLite and ELMAH will work just fine - the loader will do the right thing and look up the correct arch for SQLite. Just download both versions, run the Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt as Administrator and run

```
gacutil -i System.Data.SQLite.dll
```

with each of them.

Comment: How do I *GAC* them? (I'm sorry, I'm new to the Windows platform)

Comment: Ah, so under VS's Start Menu entry, you'll find "VS 2008 Command Prompt x86/Win64" - run that so it sets the paths right, then the tool you want is "gacutil -i"; make sure to run the 64-bit cmd prompt for 64-bit and 32-bit cmd prompt for x86!

Comment: How do you run that prompt in x64? I couldn't find it.